# How to set featured image from a variable

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have an image displayed on my post via a variable {$poster}.  How could I set this variable to a featured image?

This is what I have in my post:

```
<div class="poster"><img src="{$poster}" height="325" width="225" border="0" alt=" " />
```

Comment: What do you mean by in your post? In the post content area in the admin screen? In your template?

Comment: I have a plugin that posts an image on my post through this variable {$poster} which is basically a url. How can I take this variable and use it as a featured image?

Comment: The code that I've pasted above is from an html file within the plugin.

Comment: You've successfully made it more confusing. You should ask this question in the plugins support forum, or tell us the name of the plugin. Not enough info, also very localized and unlikely to help others (voting to close).

Comment: @Jerry If you can provide some more information as mentioned, others may be able to to help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only run PHP from .php files, not .html, etc. So you should make sure you got that one right. But also you could try to use `global $poster;` for where you defined it and for where you are calling it. For example:
in **widget.php** `global $poster;` and in 
**output.php** `global $poster; echo $poster;`